# Morbius speaks of a realignment in "Forbidden Planet"

Tags: forbidden-planet

In showing the captain and doctor around the Krell lab following their tour, Morbius says that sixteen years ago he noticed a total realignment of the system had taken place — so four years after his expedition arrived. That realignment was never spoken of again. What was its significance?

Comment: Could you add an exact quotation, and/or a link to a video clip showing this? It might help jog readers' memories.

Comment: https://youtu.be/HHXfMjp2zqI?t=185 - but as I understand it, it's "a minor alteration", not a "total realignment".

Comment: Not sure but i suspect it is that the system has refitted itself for human minds.

Answer (score 8):

I always assumed that the precipitating event was Altaira's birth.

> **Morbius:**  I have reason to believe that sixteen years ago a minor alteration was performed throughout the entire eight thousand cubic miles of its own fabric.

The sixteen years puts the event plausibly around the time of Alta's birth, or shortly thereafter.

Morbius is unaware that he (having been attuned to the Krell systems) has virtually complete (albeit unconscious) control over the planetary machinery.  However, Altaira also has a degree of control over some of the Krell apparatus's creations—specifically the artificial animals, although her control (or, equivalently, the animals' docility in her presence) only lasts while she is under her father's thumb.  At some point, Morbius (as master of the machines) had to imbue her with this ability, which could have happened when she was born or at some point when she was quite young.